# Rails nested attributes: validates_uniqueness_of doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord, nested-attributes

I have 3 models:

```
class UserLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_languages
    has_many :users, :through => :user_languages
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_languages, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :languages, :through => :user_languages
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_languages, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I'm using [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) to help user select which language(s) they can speak in. The CRUD for that is working fine.

But, I can't validate uniqueness of the UserLanguage. I try this 2 syntax but they didn't work for me:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :language_id, scope: :user_id
validates :language_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => user_id}
```

My schema for user_languages table:

```
  create_table "user_languages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "language_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  add_index "user_languages", ["language_id"], name: "index_user_languages_on_language_id", using: :btree
  add_index "user_languages", ["user_id"], name: "index_user_languages_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

What should I do to make sure one user can choose only a language once? Say, if I select English inside the dropdown, my second English will not be saved (duplicate) and rejected.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it finally:

```
class UserLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :language

    def self.delete_duplicated_user_languages(user_id)
        user_languages_ids      = UserLanguage.where(user_id: user_id).pluck(:language_id).sort
        duplicate_language_ids  = user_languages_ids.select {|language| user_languages_ids.count(language) > 1}
        duplicate_language_ids.uniq!
        keep_this_language = []
        duplicate_language_ids.each do |language_id|
            keep_this_language << UserLanguage.find_by(user_id: user_id, language_id: language_id).id
        end
        single_language = user_languages_ids.select {|language| user_languages_ids.count(language) == 1}
        single_language.each do |language|
            keep_this_language << UserLanguage.find_by(user_id: user_id, language_id: language).id
        end
        UserLanguage.where(user_id: user_id).where.not(id: keep_this_language).destroy_all
    end

end
```

I save all `UserLanguage`s first and delete them (duplicate ones) later.

Answer (score 0):

If User has and should only have one Language, then you could change the cardinality between the models:

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :language
end
```

Then by definition your users will only have one language at a time and your overall model will be simpler.

You can read more about active record associations and cardinalities [in this Association Basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.